# ARM Cortex M4: test from unpriviledged mode if inside interrupt

Tags: c, cortex-m, arm-mpu

I am working with the following CPU: Stellaris LM4F120H5QR Microcontroller. This CPU contains a MPU and I want to utalize this thing. But a lot of registers are no longer accessable when inside unpriviliged mode and I cannot seem to find a register which indicates that the system is inside an interrupt and is readable from unpriviliged mode.

I need this because there is code that might take a different route when called from an interrupt. If I do a wrong check from unprivileged mode, the system will immedeatly jump to access fault.

So how can I check if a function is called from an interrupt in a way that will not create a fault when called from unprivileged mode?

Answer (score 1):

According to [ARM's documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBIBGJ.html) the `CONTROL` and `ISR` registers might be just what you need.

So, using the CMSIS prototypes, the code might look like:

```
if (__get_IPSR() || !(__get_CONTROL() & 0x1)) 
{
   /* Privilged code */
}
else
{
   /* Unprivileged code */
}
```

As far as I know, reading those should be allowed even to a user thread.

Comment: According to that page both registers can only be access in privileged mode. Or am I misreading?

Comment: The ARM manual indeed indicates these registers as privileged, but reading from CONTROL, at least, should be also available in non-privileged mode. There's a sample in the "Definitive Guide to a Cortex M3" book, where this code is used in user thread context.